# String calculator kata

Tags: c#, unit-testing, calculator

I'm new to C# and just tried the [String Calculator Kata](http://osherove.com/tdd-kata-1/) for practice. What I like to know is if you (as more experienced C# programmers)  have some suggestions for improvement with the end result (concerning readability, good practices, C# specific idioms etc.)

Code:

```
public class StringCalculator
{
    private const char DefaultDelimiter = ',';

    public int Add(string input)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
            return 0;

        IEnumerable<string> tokens = Tokenize(input);
        IEnumerable<int> numbers = tokens.Select(ConvertToNumber).ToList();

        CheckForNegativeNumbers(numbers);

        return numbers.Sum();
    }

    private static void CheckForNegativeNumbers(IEnumerable<int> numbers)
    {
        List<int> negativeNumbers = numbers.Where(number => number < 0).ToList();

        if (negativeNumbers.Count > 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("Negatives not allowed: " + FormatNegativeNumbers(negativeNumbers));
    }

    private static string FormatNegativeNumbers(IEnumerable<int> negativeNumbers)
    {
        return string.Join(" ", negativeNumbers);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<string> Tokenize(string input)
    {
        char delimiter = DefaultDelimiter;

        if (CustomDelimiterSpecified(input))
        {
            delimiter = ParseCustomDelimiter(ref input);
        }
        else
        {
            input = ReplaceAlternativeDelimitersWithCommas(input);    
        }

        return input.Split(delimiter);
    }

    private static char ParseCustomDelimiter(ref string input)
    {
        char customDelimiter = input[2];
        input = input.Substring(4);
        return customDelimiter;
    }

    private static bool CustomDelimiterSpecified(string input)
    {
        return input.StartsWith("//");
    }

    private static string ReplaceAlternativeDelimitersWithCommas(string input)
    {
        return input.Replace("\n", ",");
    }

    private static int ConvertToNumber(string input)
    {
        return int.Parse(input);
    }
}
```

Tests:

```
[TestClass]
public class StringCalculatorTest
{
    private StringCalculator calculator = new StringCalculator();

    [TestMethod]
    public void Add_EmptyString_ReturnsZero()
    {
        int result = calculator.Add("");

        Assert.AreEqual(0, result);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Add_OneNumber_ReturnsNumber()
    {
        int result = calculator.Add("42");

        Assert.AreEqual(42, result);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Add_TwoNumbersDelimitedWithComma_ReturnsSum()
    {
        int result = calculator.Add("1,2");

        Assert.AreEqual(3, result);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Add_MultipleNumbersDelimitedWithComma_ReturnsSum()
    {
        int result = calculator.Add("1,2,3");

        Assert.AreEqual(6, result);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Add_TwoNumbersDelimitedWithNewLine_ReturnsSum()
    {
        int result = calculator.Add("1\n2");

        Assert.AreEqual(3, result);
    }


    [TestMethod]
    public void Add_TwoNumbersDelimitedWithCustomDelimiter_ReturnsSum()
    {
        string input = "//;\n1;2";
        int result = calculator.Add(input);

        Assert.AreEqual(3, result);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentException))]
    public void Add_NegativeNumber_ThrowsArgumentException()
    {
        calculator.Add("-1");
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Add_NegativeNumber_ErrorMessageContainsNumber()
    {
        try
        {
            calculator.Add("-1");
            Assert.Fail();
        }
        catch (ArgumentException e)
        {
            Assert.AreEqual("Negatives not allowed: -1", e.Message);
        }
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Add_MultipleNegativeNumbers_ErrorMessageContainsAllNegativeNumbers()
    {
        try
        {
            calculator.Add("-1,2,-3");
            Assert.Fail();
        }
        catch (ArgumentException e)
        {
            Assert.AreEqual("Negatives not allowed: -1 -3", e.Message);
        }            
    }         
}
```

Answer (score 6):

In regards to your implementation, I can see no reason that it needs to be an instance class so I would suggest making the class static. There is no reason to have to create a `Calculator` to call `Add`, it returns the result of the addition and maintains no state. If you were maintaining a running total and had a `Subtract` method etc then it would make sense as an instance class as you wouldn't want 2 separate callers to share the same running total.

This method may be better expressed as a Linq query:

```
private static void CheckForNegativeNumbers(IEnumerable<int> numbers)
{
    List<int> negativeNumbers = numbers.Where(number => number < 0).ToList();

    if (negativeNumbers.Count > 0)
        throw new ArgumentException("Negatives not allowed: " + FormatNegativeNumbers(negativeNumbers));
}
```

Using `.Any()` will return true as soon as it finds a match rather than having to enumerate the whole collection (I know in this case you will have a limited number of values in `numbers` but it's a good method to know about). Also, it saves having to create a list just to check the count so it's more efficient too (the amount by which will depend on the implementation and number of values, but again it's a good practice to stick to where it makes sense).

```
private static void CheckForNegativeNumbers(IEnumerable<int> numbers)
{
    if (numbers.Any(number => number < 0))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Negatives not allowed: " + FormatNegativeNumbers(negativeNumbers));
    }
}
```

Also, avoid inline or unbraced `if` conditions - always wrap the body in braces. It makes it easier to follow the code and helps prevent bugs being introduced at a later stage if additional actions needs to happen inside the same `if` body.

In terms of your tests, I have a few suggestions.

Firstly, change these two tests:

```
[TestMethod]
[ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentException))]
public void Add_NegativeNumber_ThrowsArgumentException()
{
    calculator.Add("-1");
}

[TestMethod]
public void Add_NegativeNumber_ErrorMessageContainsNumber()
{
    try
    {
        calculator.Add("-1");
        Assert.Fail();
    }
    catch (ArgumentException e)
    {
        Assert.AreEqual("Negatives not allowed: -1", e.Message);
    }
}
```

The `ExpectedException` attribute is known to be problematic as you can't verify which method call has thrown an exception in the case that you have multiple method calls (see [this blog post](http://jamesnewkirk.typepad.com/posts/2008/06/replacing-expec.html) for further details). Another problem is the one you are facing in the second method whereby you want to verify the exception. If your testing framework has it (both NUnit and xUnit do) use `Assert.Throws` instead.

```
var exception = Assert.Throws<ArgumentException>(() => calculator.Add("-1"));
```

This allows you to verify the exact method that should fail and also capture the exception if you want to check the message, param name etc.

Secondly, stop using a shared instance of `calculator` across all tests. They should all be isolated from each other. One test method should not have the ability to potentially alter the state for another test method. I know in this example, there is no shared state in calculator and in this instance it would be alleviated by making the class static as I mentioned above, but it's a good practice to get into regardless.

Personally I consider calling `Assert.Fail()` a code smell, it's use should be carefully considered to see if there is a different way the test can be written. If for whatever reason you decide that you need to call it, at least use the overload to specify a failure reason so that if the test fails you have some clue as to why: `Assert.Fail("An ArgumentException should have been thrown since we have called Add with a negative number");`.

Something else you may want to consider as far as test names go is re-wording the test names to be more contextual to the desired behaviour. For example `Add_EmptyString_ReturnsZero` could be expressed as `WhenCallingAdd_WithAnEmptyString_ZeroShouldBeReturned` the method name is slightly longer but it defines the specification of the behaviour. This will help you (and other developers) understand *how* your application should behave at a later stage.

Comment: +1, this has been very useful, thank you very much for your input, you have some very good points.

Comment: I'm confused, you advocate moving it to a static class with static methods, then you say don't have an instance class running across all tests in your unit tests because they might step on each other.  A static class introduces the same problem.

Comment: @JeffVanzella you might reread the last sentence of this paragraph where he states that this does not apply here (when using the static class) but is a good general practice.

Answer (score 1):

I think your answer was pretty well done. Really, for that test, you probably got near full marks. I know that wasn't much of an answer, but there really wasn't much to add to your code.

Comment: +1 thank you. Actually, that is a valuable answer for me as this is all new for me and I can't always judge well if this is the way to do it in C#.

Comment: It was very good, really. You're code was very readable, with good naming, clear refactoring, and everything. I can't really think of ways to do it more clear than you did. Good job.

Comment: By the way, what did you program in previously anyway? Just curious.

Comment: Mainly Delphi for my job, occasionally some Java in my free time.

Comment: Mostly what you do in Java would be correct in C#. Of course there are significant differences but there're still more of the same thing than otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I like your solution as well.  The only thing I might consider doing differently is making input a private instance variable which would mean all your input parameter requirements to the methods would no longer be required.

Something like:

```
public class StringCalculator
{
    private const char DefaultDelimiter = ',';
    private string _input = "";

    public int Add(string input)
    {
        _input = input;

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_input))
            return 0;

        IEnumerable<string> tokens = Tokenize();
        IEnumerable<int> numbers = tokens.Select(ConvertToNumber).ToList();

        CheckForNegativeNumbers(numbers);

        return numbers.Sum();
    }

    private static void CheckForNegativeNumbers(IEnumerable<int> numbers)
    {
        var negativeNumbers = numbers.Where(number => number < 0).ToList();

        if (negativeNumbers.Any())
            throw new ArgumentException("Negatives not allowed: " + FormatNegativeNumbers(negativeNumbers));
    }

    private static string FormatNegativeNumbers(IEnumerable<int> negativeNumbers)
    {
        return string.Join(" ", negativeNumbers);
    }

    private IEnumerable<string> Tokenize()
    {
        char delimiter = DefaultDelimiter;

        if (CustomDelimiterSpecified())
        {
            delimiter = ParseCustomDelimiter();
        }
        else
        {
            ReplaceAlternativeDelimitersWithCommas();
        }

        return _input.Split(delimiter);
    }

    private char ParseCustomDelimiter()
    {
        char customDelimiter = _input[2];
        _input = _input.Substring(4);
        return customDelimiter;
    }

    private bool CustomDelimiterSpecified()
    {
        return _input.StartsWith("//");
    }

    private void ReplaceAlternativeDelimitersWithCommas()
    {
        _input = _input.Replace("\n", ",");
    }

    private static int ConvertToNumber(string input)
    {
        int intValue;
        return int.TryParse(input, out intValue) ? intValue : 0;            
    }
}
```

Comment: @codesparkle yep :)